# Error "Docker: invalid publish opts format " runing Graphviz docker container on Mac Os

Tags: macos, docker, graphviz

I'm completely new to docker and am using it for the first time.

I have installed Docker Desktop for Mac OS and run the 'Hello-world' container successfully. I am now trying to run this 'omerio/graphviz-server' from https://hub.docker.com/r/omerio/graphviz-server (which is what I really want Docker for) and although the 'docker pull omerio/graphviz-server' command completes successfully:

```
devops$ docker pull omerio/graphviz-server
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from omerio/graphviz-server
863735b9fd15: Pull complete 
4fbaa2f403df: Pull complete 
44be94a95984: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
ae092b5d3a08: Pull complete 
d0edb8269c6a: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:02cd3e2355526a927e951a0e24d63231a79b192d4716e82999ff80e0893c4adc
Status: Downloaded newer image for omerio/graphviz-server:latest
```

the command to start the container (given on https://hub.docker.com/r/omerio/graphviz-server): `'docker run -d -p : omerio/graphviz-server'` gives me the error message:

```
devops$ docker run -d -p : omerio/graphviz-server
docker: invalid publish opts format (should be name=value but got ':').
See 'docker run --help'.
```

Searching for this error message returns no information at all. I see that the container in question was last updated over 3 years ago - could it be an old format that Docker no longer supports?

Answer (score 3):

`-p` option of `docker run` command binds ports between host and container (see [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose)), and its usage is most of the time the following :

```
docker run <other options> \
    -p <port on the host>:<port in the container> \
    <my_image> <args>
```

As for your example : it seems that running the image needs an argument (the port in the container). Let's choose `8080` for example (that means port `8080` will be used by the application inside the container).

If you want to access it directly on your host (via `localhost`), you should bind `8080` port (in the container, the port we chose previously) to any available port on your host (let's say `8081`), like this :

```
docker run \
    -p 8081:8080 \
    omerio/graphviz-server 8080
```

You should now be able to access the application (port `8080` of the application running in the container) from your host via `localhost:8081`.